# Webrole - Multiple hostHeader on a single Binding?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-configuration

Is it possible in Azure to have multiple hostHeader on a single Binding or is it mandatory to create one Binding for each hostheader ?

Example :

```xml
<Sites>
...
<Site name="sample.com" physicalDirectory="..\sample.com">
<Bindings>
    <Binding name="ep_sample" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.sample1.com,www.sample2.com,www.sample3.com" />
</Bindings>
</Sites>
```

Or do I have to create each binding entry for single hostHeader (knowing that the site path is the same)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it has to be done like this:

```
<Sites>
...
<Site name="sample.com" physicalDirectory="..\sample.com">
<Bindings>
    <Binding name="ep_sample1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.sample1.com" />
    <Binding name="ep_sample2" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.sample2.com" />
</Bindings>
</Sites>
```

Comment: Ok thank you, not a big deal but i was a little lazy about the unique naming of each binding.